# How to user Parallel.Foreach for ADO RecordSet in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am doing SSIS project for ETL. My senario is as follow:

[image]

I want to have parallel looping for API call script component. How can I call API using parallel.foreach OR any other alternative?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Where's the code? What does the script do? Have you tried just using `Parallel.ForEach`? Although that may not do what you think it will. SSIS *already* uses separate threads for each step in a pipeline. If you use `Parallel.ForEach` you'll steal threads from rest of the pipeline. `Parallel.ForEach` is unsuitable for IO work too, so you'll just end up blocking the CPU cores for no reason. You need `async/await` if you want to execute multiple concurrent HTTP calls

Comment: Unfortunately, SSIS is a bit of a relic and *doesn't* support async/await. SQLCLR doesn't either. If you want to work with HTTP calls it may be better to write a .NET Core program using the Dataflow or Channel classes to build a pipeline, call REST services using as many concurrent calls as you want, batch the results and insert them using SqlBulkCopy. Editing that program will be a lot faster and easier than editing a Script component too.

Comment: I agree. For proper parallel processing, you need a .Net Core app using async/await. That doesn't always get you all the way either. You either need a Task.WhenAll() or an action block to maximize threading.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have alternatively write .NET code and check it, for approx 17000 API calls, it takes around 5-6 min in parallel.foreach. I wanted to check whether this is possible with SSIS.